# C malloc works, but it should not

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, malloc

For my linear algebra code I need to allocate memory for a lower triangular matrix,
represented by a one dimensional array. I was experimenting with how many elements I can allocate and
stumbled upon a weird behaviour. If I set `double bottom_row_final` to be anything above `240.0`, `malloc`
fails and my machine cannot allocate enough memory, but setting it to `410.0`, `malloc` does not fail, and
my code crashes later in the `for` loop when initialising the array after `30` or so iterations (out of
bounds indexing excluded as possible error source). Does someone know what is happening here?

```
//array.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void vector_alloc(int N, double **pM) {
    if ((*pM = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double))) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc failed!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void vector_free(double **pM) {
    free(*pM);
    *pM = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    double grid_step = 0.0125;
    double bottom_row_final = 410.0;     //  230 works, 240 and above does not allocate anymore, but 410 does 

    int bottom_row_elements = (int)(bottom_row_final / grid_step) + 1;
    int lower_triangular_matrix_elements = bottom_row_elements * (bottom_row_elements + 1) / 2;
    double *matrix;
    vector_alloc(lower_triangular_matrix_elements, &matrix);
    int index_jumper = 0;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    for (int i = 0; i <= bottom_row_elements; i++) {      
        if (i < bottom_row_elements) {
            printf("\n%d\t%d", index_jumper, lower_triangular_matrix_elements - 1);
            matrix[index_jumper] = 1.0;
            printf("\tInitialized with value");
            index_jumper += (bottom_row_elements - i);
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    vector_free(&matrix);
}
```

I tried debugging the code and I got segmentation errors (obviously) but `malloc` should not
even be able to allocate the memory for `double bottom_row_final` above `240.0`.

Comment: Not related to your question, but bad habits should be squashed early. If your program fails, it should return non-zero.  And error messages belong on stderr.  eg `if( (*pm = ...) == NULL ) { perror("malloc"); exit(1); }` (or, even better, `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
int lower_triangular_matrix_elements = bottom_row_elements * (bottom_row_elements + 1) / 2;
```

When `bottom_row_elements` is larger than `46340`, the multiplication causes a signed arithmetic overflow, which has undefined behavior.  Depending on the actual value, the result may be negative or positive, causing `malloc()` to either fail because the request is far too large, or to succeed but with an amount of memory that is lower than needed, causing further undefined behavior when accessing beyond the end of the allocated size.

You should use `size_t` for the computations instead of `int`.

```
//array.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void vector_alloc(size_t N, double **pM) {
    // Allocate the array, initialized to 0.0, assuming IEEE 754 doubles
    if ((*pM = (double *)calloc(N, sizeof(double))) == NULL) {
        printf("Fehler: malloc fehlgeschlagen!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void vector_free(double **pM) {
    free(*pM);
    *pM = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    double grid_step = 0.0125;
    double bottom_row_final = 410.0;

    size_t bottom_row_elements = (size_t)(bottom_row_final / grid_step) + 1;
    size_t lower_triangular_matrix_elements = bottom_row_elements * (bottom_row_elements + 1) / 2;
    double *matrix = NULL;
    vector_alloc(lower_triangular_matrix_elements, &matrix);
    size_t index_jumper = 0;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bottom_row_elements; i++) {      
        printf("\n%zu\t%zu",
               index_jumper, lower_triangular_matrix_elements - 1);
        matrix[index_jumper] = 1.0;
        printf("\tInitialized with value");
        index_jumper += bottom_row_elements - i;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    vector_free(&matrix);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for editing and making my question more concise, and of course answering. I tried using size_t and malloc still manages to allocate the memory even though it should not. Maybe I should mention that I am on Windows and using MinGW's gcc port.

Comment: Try the above modified version: `size_t` is much larger than `int` on Windows 64-bits, and it must be used for all sizes and index variables.  You should be able to allocate the array of 537,936,400 doubles, which is 4.3GB, unless your system prevents such large blocks.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I tried using size_t but malloc still allocated even though it should not. Switching from malloc to calloc made it not allocate anymore, which is good, but why does malloc still allocate for this specific numbers when the limit has been surpassed well beyond?

Comment: @Daniel: `calloc` and `malloc` should behave the same.. Are you sure about the arguments?  I used `calloc()` to get zero initialization for free. depending on the OS, It is possible that the array be allocated as a sparse array with many shared pages.  4.3 GB is not necessarily such a large number, my laptop has 24 GB and I can allocate 4.3 GB in a process without much difficulty.

Comment: Hi, I agree, they should behave the same, and they do so for every number bottom_row_final above 240.0. But for 410.0 calloc fails, and malloc goes through, even though I am using size_t. My system only has 8 GB and I would need to close all programs so that my code can allocate 4.3GB. It is really mysterious.

Comment: @Daniel: your system may be able to allocate 4.3 GB even as you only have 8 GB, thanks to virtual memory.  You should enforce an upper limit by manually testing it.

Comment: I simplified the testing and here is something weird. If I try to allocate 400 million double elements, malloc and calloc fails. If I try to allocate 537 million double elements, calloc fails but malloc goes through and crashes later on when accessing the array elements. How can I enforce an upper limit if I have this weird behaviour?

Comment: @Daniel: can you try adding `memset(*pM, 0, N * sizeof(double))` in `vector_alloc` and see if it crashes there?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have added memset(*pM, 0, N * sizeof(double)) in vector_alloc, and malloc still goes through and crashes afterwards when accessing the array elements.

Comment: Sorry, to be more precise, it does not crash at memset, it is crashing later in the for loop

Comment: @Daniel: can you add `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf` and see where it crashes

Comment: Hi, I added fflush(stdout), and for 537000000 elements (which should not be possible to allocate) it crashes at initialising the 129795th element

Answer (score -1):

I tried replicating your problem, but I could not. Are you sure that malloc() really worked? Do you get an error message, running it without debug?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, my array allocating function prints an error if malloc fails and exits. In this case for setting double bottom_row_final to 410.0 my code continues to run and later on crashes in the for loop.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. When you have enough reputation, you will be able to comment on questions. [You should refrain from posting comments or questions as answers.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265783/is-it-ok-to-use-an-answer-to-comment-if-you-lack-the-reputation-to-comment)